# Append data from List<T> to text file

Tags: c#, file-io, collections

I am doing a little home project to learn more about collections and FileIO.

I have made a little racing app where the user enters the racers details all of which are strings, and these details are inserted into a List list and then once the user clicks the 'save' button the contents of the list are extracted to a text file. I have successfully been able to write to the text file however I now want to change this so I am able to append the data to the text file instead of the previous data being overwritten each time the data is written to the text file, I am having trouble doing this as I am using the AppendAllText().

Here is how my People class handles the input of data to the list:

```
class People
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Car { get; set; }
        public string Place { get; set; }
        public List<string> myList = new List<string>();
        public void ShowList()
        {           
                for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("" + myList[i] + "\n|");
                }
        }
        public void AddToList()
        {
            myList.Add("Name: " + Name + " Car: " + Car + " Place: " + Place);
        }
    }
```

and this is my Form1 class with the main method which handles the events and sends the values to the list in the People class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        People person = new People();
        string path = @"C:\Users\Keil\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CarRacingArrList\racers.txt";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();          
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            person.ShowList();          
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        
            person.Name = textBox1.Text;
            person.Car = textBox2.Text;
            person.Place = textBox3.Text;
            person.AddToList();
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox3.Text = "";
        }
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(path, person.myList.OfType<string>().ToString());                    
        }
    }
```

As you can see I am using the AppendAllText() method where I am passing the path of the text file and the contents of the list. When data is written to the text file it appends this to the end: System.Linq.Enumerable+d__aa`1[System.String]
instead of the actual data stored into myList.

It looks like is returning the object type instead of the actual data

Is there something in my code that I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not call `ToString` after `OfType`. Use `string.Join` to concatenate all the lines.

```
File.AppendAllText(path, string.Join(Environment.NewLine, person.myList));
```

Or just use `File.AppendAllLines`

```
File.AppendAllLines(path, person.myList);
```

I have also removed the `OfType` call because it is redundant, you have already a  `List<string>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: `File.AppendAllLines();`?

```
File.AppendAllLines(path, person.myList.OfType<string>());
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.